Movie titled with late 80s song title or lyric that reveals a suicide pact amongst a group of reunited college friend
The setting is a rented vacation home atop a steep hill on a rocky coastline.  As the film progresses the members of the group take their lives and the audience learns of the pact.  There is a scene where one of the surviving members berates a local female cop for not having noticed what was going on at the house.  "What kind of (police) are you???" And points out that she saw what only could have three freshly dug graves.  Can only remember that there was just one big name actor in the cast.  It would have been released some time after 2010. US release.

You are looking for I Melt With You with Rob Lowe. The local female cop was played by Carla Gugino.

When four 40-something college friends meet up for their annual reunion, things start to spiral out of control, and a pact they made as young men is revisited.

Trailer: 



Thank you for this answer.  Now I can stop bugging all my old college friends from the late 80s.

You are welcome.
